# Meeting potential supervisor

Tags: research-process, research-undergraduate

I am going to meet a potential supervisor for honours project in 1 week. Its first of a kind meeting for me. I would appreciate any advice on what to expect, would it be a formal or informal meeting and how I should prepare for it.? I am new to this forum, so sorry if this is a repetitive question.

Comment: Also see [How do you prepare for a meeting with a potential masters thesis advisor?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36553/how-do-you-prepare-for-a-meeting-with-a-potential-masters-thesis-advisor) (although you are an undergrad, not a masters student, the advice still applies).